# PHP is working in command line but error 502 in browser

Tags: php, php-7.3, bad-gateway

Please help me, my server is crashed, for static files it's fine, but my server throws **`error 502`** bad gateway for every `php` script run from browser. I created a simple `test.php` script, when I run this scrip from command line using `php test.php` it's working, but when I try to open it from my web address `mydomainname(dot)com/test.php` or `ip_address/test.php` it got 502 bad gateway.

Please help me or give me some suggestions about what to check. I'm so confused because everything looks normal here. I'm using `php 7.3` and `Ubuntu 16.04` by the way

Comment: check `/var/log/apach2/error_log`

Comment: What web server are you using? Nginx? Apache? Some other server? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You most likely are using an Apache / Nginx with php-fpm setup. In that case, please check if your php-fpm service is running. If yes, please then check if your Apache / Nginx setting is correctly configured for the php-fpm backend.

Answer (score 0):

PHP works because you call it directly with `PHP text.php`
When you try to open a page with a browser, you need a web server. Something like Apache or Nginx. **You have an error because you are error on your web server configuration**.
Check the log of web server to find out the problem.